# Totalling up numbers within ArrayList out displaying

Tags: java

I want to output the total of some numbers in a text file, with the use of an `ArrayList` to seek them out etc, I am unsure of how I would do this? here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayListOfNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner (new File("numbers.txt"));

        while (Scan.hasNext()){
            numbers.add(Scan.nextLine());
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){ 
            System.out.println(numbers.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println("")

        Scan.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: a good initial step would be to parse the strings into integer, either with `Integer.parseInt(string)` or by using the scanner's `nextInt()` method. Once you've done that, it is a simple matter of summing the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner (new File("numbers.txt"));
        double sum = 0;
        while (Scan.hasNext()){
            sum += Double.parseDouble(Scan.nextLine());
        }

        System.out.println(sum);

        Scan.close();
    }
```